# getting the age from RFC Mex

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, slice

I have a data frame where I'm trying to get the age of the user, but the problem is that there is no birth date, so here in my country exist some kind of tax ID where you can get this data:

`ABCD971021XZY` or `ABCD971021`

Where the first 4 letters represent the name and last name and the numbers are the birthday date
in the case above would be 1997/10/21

At this point I've already tried this:

```py
# To slice the RFC
df_v['new_column'] = df_v['RFC'].apply(lambda x: x[4:10])


# Trying to gt the date
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
s = "971021"
date = datetime(year=int(s[0:2]), month=int(s[2:4]), day=int(s[4:6]))

OUT: 0097-10-21
```

What I'm looking for is to look something like this.

```
1997-10-21
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the millenium and century are not given explicitly in the tax ID, and there is no single way to convert from a two-digit year to a four-digit year.

e.g. 971021 tells you that the birth year is xx97, but for all `datetime` knows, that could mean the year 1597 or 1097 or 2397.

You as the programmer will have to decide how to encode your assumptions about what millenium and century a person was most likely born in. For example, a simplistic (untested) solution could be:

```
year_last_two = int(s[0:2])
# If the year given is less than 20, this person was most likely born in the 2000's
if year_last_two < 20:
    year = 2000 + year_last_two
# Otherwise, the person was most likely born in the 1900's
else:
    year = 1900 + year_last_two
date = datetime(year=year, month=int(s[2:4]), day=int(s[4:6]))
```

Of course, this solution only applies in 2019, and also assumes no one is more than 100 years old. You could make it better by using the current year as the splitting point.